# How to translate Event-Condition-Action rules to Alloy

Tags: alloy

How can we translate Event-Condition-Action rules to Alloy (http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the following slides to learn more about the event idiom in Alloy

http://people.csail.mit.edu/dnj/talks/lipari05/lectures/lipari-lecture4.pdf