# Alloy Facts Declaration

Tags: alloy

I have gone through a problem statement,like: 
A surgeon must operate on three patients, but has only two pairs of gloves. There must be no
cross-contamination: the surgeon must not come into contact with the blood of any patient,  and
no patient must come into contact with the blood of another patient. The surgeon needs two hands to work. How does she do it? Express this problem in Alloy, and use the analyzer to find a solution.

I already decalared few signatures but I stuck at the declaration of requires facts and predicates. Can anyone help me out? My codes are:

```
    module Question1

    sig Doc_Patient {
doc : one Surgeon,
patient: set Patient,
relation1: doc one->one Hand,
//relation2: hand one->set Gloves
//relation3: 
    }

   sig Surgeon{
//hands: one Hand,
blood1: one Blood   
  }
   sig Blood { }
    one sig Hand {
material: set Gloves
  }
  sig Gloves { }
    sig Patient { 
blood2: one Blood 
   } 
 fact {

 } 
 pred show( ){ }
  run show for 1 Doc_Patient,1 Surgeon,1 Hand,4 Blood,3 Patient,2 Gloves
```

\
thanx in advance

Answer (score 4):

I think this problem calls for the "[event idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077822/how-to-translate-event-condition-action-rules-to-alloy)" in Alloy.  You need to model all different kinds of events that can happen (doctor performing an operation on a patient, doctor putting gloves on, doctor taking gloves off, doctor turning a glove inside out), the allowed transitions between the events, and for each transition specify all the things that get contaminated.  Then you ask the Alloy Analyzer to find you a sequence of events such that in the end the doctor operated on all three patients and no one got contaminated.

It is not a trivial task, especially because you'll have to model the fact that the doctor can be wearing multiple gloves at a given time (which is required to solve this problem), but quite doable in Alloy.  Here is how you might start solving it

```alloy
open util/ordering[Time] as T0
open util/boolean

sig Time{}

sig GloveSide {
  // sides can get contaminated over time
  contaminated: Bool -> Time
} 

sig Glove {
  // sides can change over time
  inner: GloveSide -> Time,
  outer: GloveSide -> Time
}

sig Patient{}

one sig Doctor {
  // doctor can change gloves over time
  leftHand: (seq Glove) -> Time,
  rightHand: (seq Glove) -> Time
} 

abstract sig Event {
  // pre- and post-state times for this event
  pre, post: one Time
}

sig Operate extends Event {
  patient: one Patient
}{
  // precondition: clean gloves
  // ...

  // postcondition: outer gloves not clean, everything else stays the same
  // ...
}

sig TakeGlovesOff extends Event {
} {
  // ...
}

sig PutGlovesOn extends Event {
} {
  // ...
}

fact transitions {
  all t: Time - T0/last |
    let t' = t.next |
      some e: Event { 
        e.pre = t 
        e.post = t'
      }
}    

run {
  // all three patients operated
} for 7 but exactly 2 Glove, exactly 4 GloveSide, exactly 3 Patient, 5 Int
```